# F test with python, finding the critical value

Tags: python

Using python, Is it possible to calculate the critical value on F distribution with x and y degrees of freedom? In other words, I need to calculate the critical value given a x degrees of freedom and a confidence level 5%, but i do not see the table from statistical books, is it posible to get it with any function from python?

For example, I want to find the critical value for a F distribution with 3 an 39 degrees of freedom for 5% of confidence level. The answer should be: 2.85

Comment: The `scipy` [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.f.html) for the F-distribution might be helpful. I'm still looking for other resources around this, as there doesn't seem to be much in the way of a critical value "lookup."

Answer (score 23, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`scipy.stats.f.ppf`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.f.html), which gives the inverse of the cdf:

```
>>> import scipy.stats
>>> scipy.stats.f.ppf(q=1-0.05, dfn=3, dfd=39)
2.8450678052793514
>>> crit = _
>>> scipy.stats.f.cdf(crit, dfn=3, dfd=39)
0.95000000000000007
```

Comment: what exactly is dfn since the the degree of freedom is 39?

Answer (score 1):

Just to make dfn and dfd a little more clear for DSM's answer / scipy.stats:

`dfn` denotes **number of degrees of freedom** that the estimate of variance used in the **numerator**.

`dfd` is the **number of degrees of freedom** that the estimate of variance used in the **denominator**.

```
dfn = a-1
dfd = N-a
```

where `a` is the number of groups and `N` is the total number of subjects in the experiment.
The shape of the F distribution depends on `dfn` and `dfd`. The lower the degrees of freedom, the larger the value of F needed to be significant.